# Exact syntax for lightning-cli txprepare

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

I have tried many different forms but I cannot prepare a transaction with `lightning-cli txprepare` from the Linux prompt.

```
lightning-cli txprepare [{\"bc1qvzr0mwps952d0cdmchyd2pe5rlee5tfces5dzf\":\"all\"}] slow 1 [c2ff...:1]
lightning-cli: Incorrect 'id' in response: null

lightning-cli txprepare "[{\"bc1qvzr0mwps952d0cdmchyd2pe5rlee5tfces5dzf\":\"all\"}]" slow 1 "[c2ff...:1]"
lightning-cli: Incorrect 'id' in response: null
```

and many other trials.

What is the correct syntax?
How is it possible to avoid the double quote issue in the shell?
Is it possible to have an actual example of what SHOULD work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For readers, this issue has been resolved [here](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/3533).

Note that Gabriele's syntax was correct but that you currently cannot use unconfirmed UTXOs with `txprepare` [1] ! The documentation has been update accordingly.

[1] This caused `lightningd` to crash but has been fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

Well,
It seems that this format works:

```
lightning-cli txprepare "[{\"destinationaddress\":\"all\"}]" slow 1 "[\"txid:1\"]"
```

It is  also logic from an encoding point of view but for a reason I don't know, I always mistake something.